# route live audio output to live .wav file

Tags: windows-10, audio, vlc-media-player, music, wav

i found this nice visualisation program: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VVrf89SXvTM
i really like it, but it can only play *.wav files in the same folder as the program executable is. but i want to visualise real audio output in realtime. i tried wire audio output, via program "virtual audio cable" to audio input, and then streamed by VLC to wav audio file. that acually works, but latency depends on time between start stream and start visualizer, wich takes about few seconds, and it is no longer realtime. i guess that it can be solved by writing and erasing stream wav file simultaneously...maybe... also, someone can decompile and edit the source code of the app, but i do not have enough skills do that myself. Thanks for your help, and sry for my bad english.

Comment: Essentially, what you are asking can only be done by the maker of the app. Ask them if they might include that functionality in a future release.

Comment: I think,  that this app is no longer "supported"//"under development" if you know what i mean.